# how many constructors will be invoked if I invoke my own no arg constructor?

Tags: java, oop

Let's assume below is the code snippet then how to kknow the number of constructors invoked?

```
 private class First{ 
    }
    class Second extends First{
       public Second(){
            super();
       }
    }
    public class DriverClass extends Second{
     String class_name=null;
     public DriverClass(){
     class_name="DriverClass";
     }
      public static void main(String[] args){
       new DriverClass();
      }       
    }
```

Comment: Did you happen to add some `system.out.println` statements in each of those constructors and run it?

Comment: Only 1 because you are not creating any object of second class.

Comment: I make it four: `DriverClass(),` `Second()`, `First()`, and `Object()`, but maybe the question has been edited rapidly since first posted. 'How to know' is to analyze the code.

Comment: Maybe more than four?  The `String` object for the literal `"DriverClass"` needs to be created, but is that created ahead of time by the compiler, or is the `String()` constructor actually called at some point?  Depends on interpretation, perhaps...

Comment: @ajb It is created during class loading/initialization, or possibly before if it was already in the string pool. Not during instance construction.

Comment: Was the private keyword on `class First` intentional because I think everyone assumed it was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program gives compile time error, because private class is can not be inheritable.
In the given program the class First is prefixed with "private" keyword.

So, in line "**class Second extends First**" gives compile time error

Answer (score 1):

There are at least four constructors invoked: `DriverClass` which in turn invokes `Second` which in turn invokes `First` and of course `Object`.

Comment: Because you're out by a factor of four?

Comment: Even so the minimum answer was 2.

Comment: The String has already been constructed from the literal by the compiler and classloader in collaboration. It isn't constructed during `new DriverClass()`. It wouldn't matter how many times it had been edited, the minimum was always two, because of `DriverClass()` and `Object()`.

Comment: I say at least, because a `String` does get constructed as part of running this code, but it is a string literal as @EJP mentions.

Answer (score -1):

As DriverClass is not extending any of the classes only one constructor that is of default no-args constructor of DriverClass will be invoked.